# How is this a condition for a Majorana zero mode?

Tags: majorana-fermions

EDIT: Nevermind, I figured it out. When you apply the expression on a state, you can clearly see what it does: The new state created by applying the Majorana operators must have the same energy as the original one. So when applied on a zero-energy state, this creates a degeneracy and the so-called Majorana zero mode.

---

I am currently trying to grasp [this](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/8/8.871/www/lecnotes/FA2011/14KitaevWire06.pdf) lecture by Frank Wilczek about Majorana zero modes on an 1-dimensional wire. In equation (31), he states that a general condition for such a zero mode is 
$$
\left[ H, \sum_{j=1}^{2L} c_j \gamma_j \right] = 0,
$$
where the $c_j$ are coefficients and the $\gamma_j$ are the Majorana operators for the sites of the chain.
I'm not sure I understand why this is a general condition for a zero mode if the two operators commute.
Can anyone shed some light on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Post the edit as an answer and accept it--- this is a fine question, even though you figured out the answer yourself.

Comment: Ok. This was my first post here, so thanks for the advice. Apparently, I cannot answer my own question now, but will be allowed to after 2 more hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you apply the expression on a state, you can clearly see what it does: The new state created by applying the Majorana operators must have the same energy as the original one. So when applied on a zero-energy state, this creates a degeneracy and the so-called Majorana zero mode.